# Trying to unpack numpy array in a class using Dataset from pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, dataset, numpy-ndarray

In a tutorial for Pytorch, upon running the code:

```
import torch
import torchvision
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
import numpy as np

class WineDataset(Dataset):
    
    def __init__(self, transform=None):
        # data loading
        xy = np.loadtxt('./data/wine/wine.csv', delimiter = ",", dtype = np.float32, skiprows = 1)
        self.n_samples = xy.shape[0]
        
        # note that we do not convert to tensor here
        self.x = xy[:,1:]
        self.y = xy[:,[0]] 
        
        self.transform = transform
        
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        #dataset[0]
        sample = self.x[index], self.y[index]
        
        if self.transform:
            sample = self.transform(sample)
            
            return sample
    
    def __len__(self):
        # len(dataset)
        return self.n_samples

class ToTensor:
    def __call__(self,sample):
        inputs, targets = sample
        return torch.from_numpy(inputs), torch.from_numpy(targets)


dataset = WineDataset(transform=ToTensor())
first_data = dataset[0]
features, labels = first_data
print(type(features), type(labels))
```

the output for `print(type(features), type(labels))` shows that the variables `features` and `labels` are indeed tensors. However if  `dataset = WineDataset(transform=None)`, then `print(type(features), type(labels))` throws the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-99-17180fb44f1a> in <module>
     33 dataset = WineDataset(transform=None)
     34 first_data = dataset[0]
---> 35 features, labels = first_data
     36 print(type(features), type(labels))

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

According to the tutorial, in this case the output of `print` should indicate that `features` and `labels` are numpy arrays.

Why do I get this error then? Thanks in advance

Comment: you should unindent `return sample` in `__getitem__`because if you don't have a `self.transform` then you will return `None`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try and use the DataLoader() function on your variable. Once you've done that you can iterate over your dataset and extract the features and labels.

You could try the following:

```
dataset = WineDataset(transform=None)
data = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=1, shuffle=True)
features, labels = next(iter(data))
```

Comment: It was actually the indentation issue that @jhso mentioned, but thanks for your input.